# Why does "1 in range(2) == True" evaluate to False?

Tags: python

I came across this expression, which I thought should evaluate to True but it doesn't.

```
>> s = 1 in range(2)
>> s == True
>> True
```

Above statement works as expected but when this:

```
1 in range(2) == True
```

is executed, it evaluates to False.

I tried searching for answers but couldn't get a concrete one. Can anyone help me understand this behavior?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`1 in range(2) == True` is an operator chain, just like when you do `0 < 10 < 20`

For it to be true you would need

`1 in range(2)`

and

`range(2) == True`

to be both true. The latter is false, hence the result. Adding parenthesis doesn't make an operator chaining anymore (some operators are in the parentheses), which explains `(1 in range(2)) == True` works.

Try:

```
>>> 1 in range(2) == range(2)
True
```

Once again, a good lesson learned about not equalling things with `== True` or `!= False` which are redundant at best, and toxic at worst.

Answer (score 1):

Try to write

```
(1 in range(2)) == True
```

It has to do with parsing and how the expression is evaluated.

Comment: How exactly *is* the expression parsed without parentheses? If I run `1 in (range(2)  == True)`, it throws `TypeError: argument of type 'bool' is not iterable`.

Comment: @Optimus Can you please provide the detailed explanation of this behavior. How parsing is causing this behavior?